# problem with loading from NSUserDefaults, obj-c

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a problem with NSUserDefaults. I'm saving a name, then trying to access it later  in the code from another view controller, but it seems that my key is empty or not saved as when I display the string from the key my label is blank.

```
-(void) saveName {

    NSString *name = nameField.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:name forKey:@"playersName"];
    [defaults synchronize];
 }


-(void) viewDidLoad  // method called later on in code from different viewcontroller
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *name = [defaults objectForKey:@"playersName"];
    playerName.text = name; // player name == myLabel

    if ([[NSUsersDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"playersName"] == nil)  {
        playerName.text =@" blank";
    }    
}
```

My string doesn't seem to be saving to userdefaults as the @"blank" string keeps showing up with my label. I'm not too familiar with NSUserDefaults so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note when using `NSUserDefaults`:

1. calls to syncrhonize method is not necesary and will only make it slower if your program is multi threaded.
2. Check if the key that you use is being used by other libraries in your project
3. Check if the value that you set to the key is not nil
4. Try to use `stringForKey:` or `boolForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`

I had troubles a few times with NSUserDefaults but in the end it's usually my code that's problematic.

Comment: Cheers enrico was passing a nil value into the key its been bugging for ages its the small things you overlook!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check whether your '(void) saveName' method is being called or not... Put some breakpoint and see the result